# Restsharp 105.2.3 and Restsharp 100.0.0.0 in same project

Tags: twilio, restsharp, plivo

I need to use Plivo and Twilio in my new voice project.

Twilio requires Restsharp 105.2.3 and Plivo requires RestSharpsigned that add Restsharp 100.0.0.0 to the project.

How can i add this two vesions of Restsharp in my projet.

Thank.

Comment: Well, _my_ first attempt would be to install only the latter library and do a [binding redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx) to it so that they both use that version.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing... did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by downgrading Plivo and Twilio to the latest versions that would agree to work together:

- Plivo 1.3.7
- Twilio 3.6.20
- RestSharp 104.4.0

Answer (score 0):

As laurian said you can setup a version that in the restsharp will meet both the libraries dependencies but if you want to use the method get_numbers with the parameters whcich is available from plivo version 3, than you need another solution.

what i did because of plivo and twilio didnt fixed this issue yet is downloading last plivo source from github(because plivo library is much smaller than twilio) and changing from **RestSharpSigned 105.0.1** to **RestSharp 105.2.3** which is the last version avaliable for today.
than compile it and replace the plivo.dll in the packages folder of your solution.

i know that this solution is not prefered because you may have problems with upgrading packages but it works well and maybe on the next version someone will fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I've outlined the four general options available when you need to reference both a signed and unsigned version of an assembly [here](https://github.com/EasyPost/easypost-csharp/issues/50#issuecomment-305820879).

The option that I chose to go with was to use Brutal Dev's Strong Name Signer. It isn't ideal, but there isn't an ideal option. This is just the least amount of work. I've outlined all the steps necessary in this [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926123/is-it-possible-to-use-the-signed-restsharp-nuget-package-with-twilio/44332147#44332147)